# Getting an error while building my expo app: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: reactjs, react-native, memory, heap-memory, allocation

I've created an app with React Native and configured the app.json file. But when I'm running expo build:android I'm getting the 'Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory'  So, here is the full log:

```
transform[stderr]: 
transform[stderr]: <--- La
transform[stderr]: st few GCs --->
transform[stderr]: 
transform[stderr]: [2264:0000026E52CD3270]    77571 ms: Mark-sweep 2
transform[stderr]: 033.
transform[stderr]: 2
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: (
transform[stderr]: 2
transform[stderr]: 0
transform[stderr]: 6
transform[stderr]: 3
transform[stderr]: .
transform[stderr]: 1
transform[stderr]: )
transform[stderr]:  -> 2024.1 (
transform[stderr]: 2
transform[stderr]: 061.8)
transform[stderr]: MB, 1588.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.185, current mu = 0.085) all
transform[stderr]: oca
transform[stderr]: t
transform[stderr]: i
transform[stderr]: o
transform[stderr]: n
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: f
transform[stderr]: a
transform[stderr]: ilure
transform[stderr]: scavenge might not succeed
transform[stderr]: [2264:0000026E52CD3270
transform[stderr]: ]
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: 7
transform[stderr]: 9
transform[stderr]: 3
transform[stderr]: 2
transform[stderr]: 9
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: m
transform[stderr]: s
transform[stderr]: :
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: M
transform[stderr]: a
transform[stderr]: r
transform[stderr]: k
transform[stderr]: -
transform[stderr]: s
transform[stderr]: w
transform[stderr]: e
transform[stderr]: e
transform[stderr]: p
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: 2
transform[stderr]: 0
transform[stderr]: 3
transform[stderr]: 2
transform[stderr]: .
transform[stderr]: 7
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: (
transform[stderr]: 2
transform[stderr]: 0
transform[stderr]: 6
transform[stderr]: 1
transform[stderr]: .8) -> 2
transform[stderr]: 025.1 (2059.8) MB, 1696.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.115, current mu
transform[stderr]:  = 0
transform[stderr]: .
transform[stderr]: 0
transform[stderr]: 3
transform[stderr]: 5
transform[stderr]: )
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: a
transform[stderr]: l
transform[stderr]: l
transform[stderr]: o
transform[stderr]: c
transform[stderr]: a
transform[stderr]: t
transform[stderr]: i
transform[stderr]: o
transform[stderr]: n
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: f
transform[stderr]: a
transform[stderr]: i
transform[stderr]: l
transform[stderr]: u
transform[stderr]: r
transform[stderr]: e
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: s
transform[stderr]: c
transform[stderr]: a
transform[stderr]: v
transform[stderr]: e
transform[stderr]: n
transform[stderr]: ge might n
transform[stderr]: ot succeed
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: 
transform[stderr]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
transform[stderr]:
transform[stderr]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
transform[stderr]:  1: 00007FF6892413CF napi_wrap+109135
transform[stderr]:  2: 00007FF6891E6786 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfElementsOffset+33350
transform[stderr]:  3: 00007FF6891E7556 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfElementsOffset+36886
transform[stderr]:  4: 00007FF689AB594E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
transform[stderr]:  5: 00007FF689A9A79D v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
transform[stderr]:  6: 00007FF689944BDC v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
transform[stderr]:  7: 00007FF68994FF3A v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
transform[stderr]:  8: 00007FF68994D0E9 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
transform[stderr]:  9: 00007FF689941C81 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2033
transform[stderr]: 10: 00007FF68993FE85 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1365
transform[stderr]: 11: 00007FF6899603A7 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+183
transform[stderr]: 12: 00007FF68968DC01 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1409
transform[stderr]: 13: 00007FF689B3E49D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+463949
transform[stderr]: 14: 000003EAB9DF8BE7
```

I've never seen this error before. How is it possible to fix that? Also write if you need some additional information